# symfony2 fos user form labels

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

How can I set the form labels to something else than fos_user_registration_form_X?

For example, I have an entity field that lists entities with checkboxes, and I have the property => name set, but the label of the checkbox is indeed not the $name of the entity but fos_user_bundle seems to override that with some machine-type-label

fos_user_registration_form_access_17

And this is indeed the format of every other label in my fos_user_forms, I can't seem to find where these label strings are defined. I have no interest in translating my application later, do I have to enable translation to get human readable labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just override the Form classes that `FOSUserBundle` uses...

Read more about how to do this [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md)

Comment: I have looked in the form classes, they dont contain the labels 'fos_user_change_password_form_current' etc. can't find these strings anywhere, if I did I could simply replace them...

Comment: they're part of the form templates, if you override the Form classes you can specify what templates you wish to use for the forms